# How to add cordova plugin in IOS cordva application?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

i have cordova application in IOS.I am using x code to modifying in application. actually i am new to mac and IOS i want to know how to add custom or third party cordova plugin in my IOS application.Any tutorial or guidance any one recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You use cordova, to add plugins you use:

`cordova plugin add *pluginname*`

in the installation process it will be added to all platforms that the plugin supports. For further information about that you have to read the readme files of the plugin. They explain that for every part of their plugins better than we can here in our short texts.

If you have any further question, just ask :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command cordova **plugin add PLUGIN_NAME**
Please check the documentation from Cordova for other options to update, remove, build the plugin https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide/cli/index.html